# Determining all ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I would like to determine all the ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$. I thought of using the quotient maps

$$p_x\colon\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\to\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y),$$
$$p_y\colon\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\to\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x),$$

to form the (injective) ring map

$$f\colon\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)\to\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y)\times\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x),$$

defined by $f=p_x\times p_y$. This seems to give information about prime (and radical) ideals, because the geometry on the right-hand side is quite simple, but I'm not sure if it helps in determining the other ideals.

*Difficulty:* Since $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x)$ are unital, all ideals on the right-hand side are of the form $I\times J$, where $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x)$ respectively. However, this does not mean that ideals of the subring $\mathrm{im} f$ are of this form. For example, the ideal of $\mathrm{im} f$ generated by $f(x+y)$ is not a product (otherwise it would contain $(p_x(x),0)$, for example).

**Question:** Is there a way of using $f$ to determine all the ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$? Or perhaps another way works?

Comment: What sort of description of the ideals are you hoping for? Generally, this can be quite hard.

Comment: Hmm that's a tricky question. I was hoping there would be some kind of way to "write them all down" or enumerate them, but I'm not sure what such a description would really look like.

Comment: Well I wasn't trying to say that they were impossible to understand in your case, so let's roll with what you suggested. If you're willing to accept some algebraic geometry, then you can imagine $V(xy)$ in the affine plane. This is just the $x$-axis union the $y$-axis. Then it is quite clear what the prime ideals are going to be.  They are lines $xy=0$, $x=0$, $y=0$, or finite sets of points, or the empty set. Then one can try and use primary decomposition to describe the ideals from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition. However, this seems to be tedious....

Comment: @K02 That's good to know. I wonder if there's a way of listing all the primary ideals from prime ideals.

Comment: Try first with the $0$-dimensional quotient $k[x,y]/\langle xy,x^n,y^m \rangle$. You will see how complicated it is.

Comment: It may be helpful to break the symmetry and actually look at $R[X]/\langle pX \rangle$ for some PID $R$ and some prime $p$ in it. I would look first at some special cases for example when $R$ is a DVR.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is to classify all ideals that correspond to subschemes supported at $(0,0)$. In an algebraic language, this is the same as classifying ideals that are contained in $(x,y)$ and contain some power of $(x,y)$ (Now I am working in the ring $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy)$).

> Claim: Any such ideal $I$ is of the form $(x^n, y^m)$ or $(x^n +ay^m)$ for some non-zero complex number $a$

Proof: Let $k, l$ be minimal such that $x^k, y^l \in I$, an assume that $I \neq (x^k, y^l)$. Then there must be an element $f$ of the form $a_1 x + \ldots + a_{k-1}x^{x-1} + b_1y + \ldots + b_{l-1}y^{l-1}$. We can assume wlog that one of the $a_i$ is not $0$. Let $u = \min\{i \mid a_i \neq 0\} $. Then $u=k-1$. Why? well, look at what happens when we compute $x f$:
$$
xf = a_1x^2 + \ldots + a_{k-2}x^{k-1} + x^k\cdot \text{something} = a_ux^{u+1} + \ldots +  a_{k-2}x^{k-1} + x^k\cdot \text{something}
$$
Therefore, $x^{k-1-u}f= b_u x^{k-1} + x^k \cdot \text{something}$, and so $x^{k-1}$ would be in the ideal, a contradiction with the assumptions on $k,l$. BY the mirror argument, we see that $b_1, \ldots , b_{l-2}$ are all $0$, and so our element must be of the form $f = a x^{k-1} + by^{l-1}$. Note that $x^k, y^l \in (f)$. If there was another further element $g$, which would again be of the form $g= cx^{k-1} + dy^{l-1}$, $(c,d)$ would have to be a multiple of $(a,b)$, since otherwise, one could find $x^{k-1}$ or $y^{l-1}$ in the ideal by solving a linear system. This proves the claim.

Knowing this, one can classify all ideals corresponding to subschemes of dimension $0$.

Now, ideals corresponding to irreducible subschemes of dimension $1$. If $Y$ is such a subscheme, in particular $Y$ is an irreducible subscheme of dimension $1$ in $\mathbb C^2$, and a well known theorem says that all these subschemes are principal, i.e., correspond to a principal ideal $(f)$. Since $Y= V(f) \subset V(xy) = V(x) \cup V(y)$, we must have that $V(f) = V(x)$ or $V(y)$. Assuming the first, this implies that $\sqrt{(f)} = (x)$ in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, which forces $(f)$ to be a power of $x$ or a power of $y$.

So, the final classification of all ideals in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is as follows:

- Type 1 ideals correspond to subschemes whose irreducible components are (as sets) $V(y)$ and a finite set of points, which necessarily lie in $V(x) \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. If the points are $(0, b_1), \ldots , (0,b_q)$, each of them can come with some multiplicity $m_1, \ldots , m_q$, and there is also a multiplicity for $V(y)$, say it is $m$. The associated ideal is
  $$
  I = \left(y^m\prod_{i=1}^q(y-b_i)^{m_i}\right)
  $$
- Type 2 ideals are the same as type 1 with the roles of $x,y$ interchanged:
  $$
  I = \left(x^n\prod_{i=1}^p(x-a_i)^{n_i}\right)
  $$
- Type 3 ideals are those which are $0$-dimensional. By the above argument, these are in bijection with the set of points $a_1, \ldots a_p, b_1, \ldots , b_q$ in $\mathbb C ^*$ with multiplicities $n_1, \ldots , n_p,m_1\ldots m_q$, as well as a choice of an ideal $J = (x^n, y^m)$ (Type 3A) or $J=(x^n+ay^m)$ (Type 3B). The corresponding ideal is
  $$
  I = \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(x-a_i)^{n_i} \prod_{j=1}^q(y-b_j)^{m_j}\right)\cdot (x^n , y^m) = \left(x^n\prod_{i=1}^p(x-a_i)^{n_i}, y^m \prod_{j=1}^q(y-b_j)^{m_j}\right),
  $$
  or
  $$
  I = \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(x-a_i)^{n_i} \prod_{j=1}^q(y-b_j)^{m_j}\right)\cdot (x^n +a y^m) = \left(x^n\prod_{i=1}^p(x-a_i)^{n_i}+a y^m \prod_{j=1}^q(y-b_j)^{m_j}\right)
  $$

Therefore, all the ideals are of the form $(bf(x)+ag(y))$ or $(f(x), g(y))$ for some unique (up to scalar) polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb C[x]$ and $a,b \in \mathbb C$

Type 1, Type 2 and Type 3B ideals can be read off from the map that you suggested, and you could say that Type 3A too, but I think that the proof that these are all the ideals does not follow from just looking at the ring map $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy) \to \mathbb C[y] \times \mathbb C[x]$ (someone correct me if I am wrong)